# Mediarecorder records video but output file not playable: Camera API

Tags: android, video, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am developing background video recorder using `Service` class and using `Camera API`. Everything seems fine when I run the app. But when I play the output file, I get **"Can't play this video"** error. I have tried debugging the app but unable to figure out where lies the problem.

Here is my video recorder `Service` class:

```
public class VideoRecordingOldApiService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


    private Camera mCamera;
    private String outputFile;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private CameraCheck cameraCheck;
    private final static String TAG = "VideoRecorderService";
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private Thread thread;
    private Handler handler;


    public VideoRecordingOldApiService() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.surfaceview_layout, null);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textureView_width), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.textureView_height)));
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(

                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                PixelFormat.OPAQUE
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceView);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        cameraCheck = new CameraCheck();
        handler = new Handler();

        //Setup Notification
        final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification;

        notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.videorecordicon)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.video_recorder_notification))
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_video_text) + "...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (initCamera()) {

            thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Looper.prepare();

                    if (initRecorder()) {

                        mMediaRecorder.start();

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.video_recorder_started, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't start MediaRecorder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    public String getFileName() {

        String fileName = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            fileName = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/" + "video_record" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4";

            Log.i("Camera Recorder", fileName);
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No External Storage Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return fileName;
    }


    private boolean initCamera() {

        try {

            mCamera = cameraCheck.getDesiredCamera(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setRecordingHint(true);

            Camera.Size previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(),
                    surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight());
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.v(TAG, "Could not initialise the camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean initRecorder() {

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        outputFile = getFileName();


        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        profile.videoFrameWidth = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes().get(1).width;
        profile.videoFrameHeight = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes().get(1).height;
        profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
        profile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
        profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;


        try {
            mCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
            //mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());


            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder initialized successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "MediaRecorder failed to initialize");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    private void releaseCamera() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.lock();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            thread.interrupt();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.recording_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if (linearLayout != null) {

            windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
            linearLayout = null;
        }

        stopForeground(true);
        releaseCamera();
        thread = null;
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

**EDITS: Here is my logcat:**

```
07-09 22:32:26.022 137-137/? W/MPEG4Writer: getEncodeQualiytAdjustParam,sVideoQualityAdjustParamTable no related Quality Param
07-09 22:32:26.022 137-137/? E/MPEG4Writer: configVideoQualityAdjustParams,mVideoBitrateLowPercentage and mVideoDynamicAutoFPSDropRate are invalid, disable quality adjust
07-09 22:32:26.023 137-137/? D/MPEG4Writer: video Track  start
07-09 22:32:26.023 137-137/? D/MPEG4Writer: video Track  start,mStartTimeRealUs=222832948
07-09 22:32:26.023 137-137/? D/MPEG4Writer: Start Video MediaSource
07-09 22:32:26.024 137-137/? I/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] @@ def.nBufferCountActual = 10,
07-09 22:32:26.057 137-137/? W/CameraSource: Failed to set video buffer count to 10 due to -38
07-09 22:32:26.275 137-3729/? W/CameraSource: Timed out waiting for incoming camera video frames: 0 us
07-09 22:32:26.335 137-137/? D/MPEG4Writer: Start Video MediaSource finish, err=0
07-09 22:32:26.335 137-137/? D/MPEG4Writer: video Track track thread start OK--
07-09 22:32:26.339 137-4835/? D/MPEG4Writer: Video mNumSamples=0, mDone=0
07-09 22:32:26.574 137-3730/? D/MPEG4Writer: left_video_chunk_num=0, mInterleaveDurationUs=1000000, mBitrate=6128000
07-09 22:32:26.732 137-463/? I/CameraSource: the first video frame,mStartTimeUs=10516,RealStartTimeUs=223543464
07-09 22:32:26.802 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x479cf008, pvAlignMemVa = 0x479cf008, pvMemPa = 0x1b00008, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1b00008, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.823 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x47d21020, pvAlignMemVa = 0x47d21020, pvMemPa = 0x1b40020, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1b40020, MemSize = 1970560, ByteAlignment = 32
07-09 22:32:26.824 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x4794cce8, pvAlignMemVa = 0x4794cce8, pvMemPa = 0x1d40ce8, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1d40ce8, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.829 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x47f03020, pvAlignMemVa = 0x47f03020, pvMemPa = 0x1d80020, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1d80020, MemSize = 1970560, ByteAlignment = 32
07-09 22:32:26.830 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x438738c0, pvAlignMemVa = 0x438738c0, pvMemPa = 0x1f808c0, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1f808c0, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.841 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x480e5020, pvAlignMemVa = 0x480e5020, pvMemPa = 0x1fc0020, pvAlignMemPa = 0x1fc0020, MemSize = 1970560, ByteAlignment = 32
07-09 22:32:26.842 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x45edadc0, pvAlignMemVa = 0x45edadc0, pvMemPa = 0x21c0dc0, pvAlignMemPa = 0x21c0dc0, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.852 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x482c7020, pvAlignMemVa = 0x482c7020, pvMemPa = 0x2200020, pvAlignMemPa = 0x2200020, MemSize = 1970560, ByteAlignment = 32
07-09 22:32:26.853 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x46f7ca88, pvAlignMemVa = 0x46f7ca88, pvMemPa = 0x2400a88, pvAlignMemPa = 0x2400a88, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.853 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 1 assertion!! line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.853 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 3 assertion error line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.854 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x46f7cd00, pvAlignMemVa = 0x46f7cd00, pvMemPa = 0x2440d00, pvAlignMemPa = 0x2440d00, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.855 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 1 assertion!! line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.855 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 3 assertion error line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.856 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x43873010, pvAlignMemVa = 0x43873010, pvMemPa = 0x2480010, pvAlignMemPa = 0x2480010, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.857 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 1 assertion!! line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.857 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 3 assertion error line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.858 137-4819/? I/VDO_LOG: [M4U][eVideoMemAlloc] pvMemVa = 0x47cffad8, pvAlignMemVa = 0x47cffad8, pvMemPa = 0x24c0ad8, pvAlignMemPa = 0x24c0ad8, MemSize = 624, ByteAlignment = 1
07-09 22:32:26.858 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 1 assertion!! line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:26.858 137-4819/? E/VDO_LOG: [ERROR] 3 assertion error line 221, file(mediatek/platform/mt6572/hardware/vcodec/video_codec/sw_h264_enc/adaptor/src/h264_encoder_component_v2.c)
07-09 22:32:29.278 137-3729/? W/CameraSource: Timed out waiting for incoming camera video frames: 0 us
07-09 22:32:29.599 137-3730/? D/MPEG4Writer: left_video_chunk_num=0, mInterleaveDurationUs=1000000, mBitrate=6128000
07-09 22:32:29.799 137-4836/? D/MPEG4Writer: left_video_chunk_num=0, mInterleaveDurationUs=1000000, mBitrate=6128000
07-09 22:32:30.608 137-3730/? D/MPEG4Writer: left_video_chunk_num=0, mInterleaveDurationUs=1000000, mBitrate=6128000
```

I have been stuck on this feature for quite sometime. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?????

Comment: show your logcat output?

Comment: Hey Sohail. thanks for replying man! I have added my logcat..pls see.. @SohailZahid